# Can't save my sudoers.tmp file after correcting syntax error

Tags: sudo, syntax

I know there are a lot of questions regarding sudoer and sudoers.d directory, but i can't find the answers for my specific problems:

1. There is a syntax error on every line (in both sudoer and sudoers.d) according to the error message I get when I use sudo. How do I know what the error is? Is there some sort of template somewhere? I'm new to linux and to command lines so I don't know beans about syntax!
2. I found out that I could use pkexec visudo to edit the sudoers.d file. I made a change to the file, saved and exited. Reopened the file. The changed wasn't saved. I know that I don't really know what is wrong with the syntax, I was grasping at straws when I made a change.

I'd really appreciate any help I can get. I'm taking a beginner Linux class and was following instructions in an exercise. They shouldn't have advanced stuff like this in a beginner class IMHO!

Comment: Did you check the time on the edited file with ls -l ?  Did you use the full path on the file you edit (/etc/sudoers) ? Maybe the file got written into /root, look there too. Not sure how pkexec works, but if it uses sudo, you will have to boot from another system (install media will do) to copy the edited file to /etc.